# Slow paging with SQL query (stored procedure) in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I've got the following SQL statement that's generated in a dynamic stored procedure based on various parameters:

```
SELECT [MetadataId], [DocumentType], InvoiceNumber FROM 
( 
  SELECT [MetadataId], [DocumentType], InvoiceNumber, ROW_NUMBER() 
  OVER (ORDER BY [MetadataId] Asc) 
  AS [Row_ID] 
  FROM [Metadata] 
  WHERE ([DocumentType] = 'Invoice')
) Wrapper 
WHERE Row_ID BETWEEN 999980 AND 1000000
```

where the `Row_ID` changes based on the my grid's current page.

The above query works great when I navigate initially navigate from page 1 to page 2,3,4,5, and so forth but I can't say the same if I immediately navigate from page 1 to page 50,000 which is the last page in my test database which contains 1 million random randomly generated invoices where my page size is 20.

It takes around 29/30 seconds to load up and the RAM used by my SQL Server instance goes from around 400MB to 1.61GB.

Once the initial delay has elapsed, going to page 49999, 49998, 49997, etc... is instant or navigating back and forth between page 1 to 50000 is also instant.

I can only assume that the entire data set is somehow loaded in memory.

Additional Notes:

1. `MetadataId` is set as a primary key.
2. Other searchable columns such as `DocumentType`, `InvoiceNumber`, etc... are also indexed but not unique.
3. I need to keep using the dynamic stored procedure for various reasons but the main one being that while the field requirements change from client to client, the result being used by our app remains the same.
4. Using SQL Server 2014 Developers edition for my tests.

So my questions are:

1. Can someone explain to me what's actually happening? Is the all data being loaded in memory?
2. Is there a way to improve this? Note that I need to `Row_ID` generate by 'ROW_NUMBER() OVER' as the `WHERE` clause part of my SQL statement can change quite drastically depending on what parameter the user is searching under.

Thank you.

**UPDATE-1**

Here's the execution plan:

[image: Execution Plan]

Comment: Have you looked at the execution plan to see what's going on?  Row_ID is not indexed or the primary key?

Comment: Certainly sounds like the whole table is loaded into memory.  I suspect it has to in order to sort by a row that might not be indexed and get all the way to the end.

Comment: @RickS, Row_ID is generated by the Row_Number function which is different depending on what the user selects in the application.  So, unless all of the possible sort columns are indexed, you might be in trouble.

Comment: @Thierry, have you looked into a columnstore index?  While there are issues with it, it might solve your problem because basically you need to create an index on every (sortable) column.  Otherwise, consider non-clustered indexes on every sortable column and compress them for storage.

Comment: You should look at changing this to use the OFFSET / FETCH keywords which should make the performance more consistent. https://sqlperformance.com/2015/01/t-sql-queries/pagination-with-offset-fetch

Comment: @paulbarbin All my sortable columns are indexed (non clustered) and once the "initial" delay is gone after going to the last page, sorting is super fast as well but I can only imaging that since Row_ID is not indexed as it is created at run-time and may be the cause of the delay as it need to assign a unique id to each row but I thought, from reading various articles on the web that this was the method to use for paging but I guess this would work just fine for a smaller amount of records..

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean I will definitely look into this but it may not be immediately as I've got tonnes of other things to do. I just thought I'd be able to get a suggestion/solution to fix my query if written incorrectly but thanks for that. Love the handle btw :)

Comment: Have you tested your SP in SSMS using different parameter.Is it Dynamic SQL or what ?Given query is not much to suggest column store index or OFFSET / FETCH .I think your testing and judgement is wrong.Just from jumping page 1 to 50000 won't slow the query.what do you mean by dynamic ?

Comment: @KumarHarsh - Yes I have tested it SSMS with tonnes of different parameters, applying the same query to different 3 tables with different fields but each with 1 million record where all fields that can be searched against and/or sorted have been indexed! Yes it is Dynamic SQL and I'm not sure what you mean by my testing and judgement is wrong. If my initial query is Row_ID BETWEEN 1 AND 20, then 21 to 40 then 41 to 60, the results are instant. If I then change my Row_ID to Row_ID BETWEEN 999981 AND 1000000, it takes 28/29 secs to load, then if I decided to go to 999980 to 999960, it is instant

Comment: @KumarHarsh - Also, I'm not suggesting anywhere that my query is either 'column store index or OFFSET / FETCH'. I posted the query to hopefully highlight if I was doing something wrong or if I could do something to improve the speed of my query. @UnhandledExceptSean suggested I look into 'OFFSET/FETCH/ which I will do and @paulbarbin suggested to make sure my sortable fields were index which they are or to look at `column store index`. If you have additional suggestions, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: @Thierry post the *actual* query. You can't use `Row_ID` or `ROW_NUMBER()` in the `WHERE` clause, you'd need a CTE. If `[MetadataId]` isn't part of an index you'll end up sorting an entire table each time. Limiting by *row* number would require scanning enough rows to reach the row numbers requested. All of that would be evident in the *execution plan*. You haven't provided that though, nor the table schemas or indexes

Comment: @RickS I've now included it in my question. As you can see, there is a huge scan first which I guess is required if a Row_ID is associated at  run-time with every row and then it is used to further filter down the query.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Do you mind explaining why would a CTE would of use here? Thanks. I've now included the exec plan but I don't think it will be of much use. MetadataID is set as a primary key, all other searchable/sortable fields such as DocumentType, InvoiceNumber, ContactNumber, ContactName, Date, etc... each have an individual index (duplicate allowed) set on them.

Comment: @Thierry it's *mandatory*. You can't use a derived column's name in a WHERE clause which means this isn't the complete query. You need to use a CTE or a subquery. Post the *actual* query you used and the corresponding execution plan.

Comment: @Thierry and the execution plan *does* show what's wrong. You have to scan the entire table in order to generate the row numbers only to filter them later. UnhandledExcepSean's link shows how to fix this. OFFSET/FETCH will *remove* the row calculation and lead to better performance. You can get even better performance though if you keep the last ID of the current page and ask for the next N rows that are larger than it

Comment: Apologies to everyone who has looked at this question. I somehow messed up my query when I originally posted it and I only spotted it because @PanagiotisKanavos highlighted that something was missing, so thanks for spotting this and again, apologies to all! I've updated the query in my question.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I will look at the OFFSET/FETCH as suggested. As for keeping the last ID, I've used a similar process in the past but won't work in my scenario as ID is kept unique, it is being used by multiple tables. For example, I could have a contract and invoice tables both using the MetadataID but always be unique, so I could have MetadataID 100,300,500 IN contract and 200,400,600 in the Invoice table so with a page size of 20 for example, searching for everything within 100 and 120 would only return 100 in my invoice query which is a problem. Best thing is probably to look at OFFSET.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic sql is good,hope you are using sp_executesql.

```
Row_ID BETWEEN 1 AND 20, then 21 to 40 then 41 to 60, the results are instant
```

Because when first query is executed then plan is cache which is reuse by subsequent query between row_id BETWEEN 1 AND 20, then 21 to 40 then 41 to 60.

```
Row_ID BETWEEN 999981 AND 1000000, it takes 28/29 secs for to load
```

I guess Query optimiser create new plan for these range so it take longer to execute for first time then plan is cache.

next time row_id 999980 to 999960 execute faster because it reuse the plan.

I think it has Parameter Sniffing problem.

I think your  query has scope to optimise but can't say without looking at it.

`OFFSET / FETCH` may improve your query as it will reduce one Select statement, not sure it depend entirely on main query.

That much plan is not enough.Clustered Index Scan is not always bad.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there should be a non clustered composite index for  the columns used in the query that way all table columns in the query will be sorted together and pointing to the metedata_Id pk; or a view created using a filtered index on the where clause of the query. Disk space consumptiion for storage is expected. I have a concern that there is a order by clause using row_id that is not part of the select query columns but a renamed column..thought there should have been a error.